# What is reference collapsing in c++ and how does it work?

Tags: c++, c++17

I was trying to find resources to learn reference collapsing but couldnt find one. I am currently reading c++ primer but its explanation on reference collapsing is very confusing. Can anyone over here explain it to me with an example?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Something like this maybe: [Universal References in C++11](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)